# In C++ why is it that int variable can be declared as private data member of a class, but not string variable?

Tags: c++, string, header-files, private, member-variables

In C++ the following header file is legal

```
#ifndef    SAMPLE_H_
#define    SAMPLE_H_

class Sample {
    private:
        int number;
};

#endif
```

But the following header file is illegal

```
#ifndef
#define

class Sample {
    private:
        string name;
};

#endif
```

Why is it like that?

In my case I have the following header file:

**Alphabet.h**

```
#include <string>

#ifndef         ALPHABET_H_
#define         ALPHABET_H_


class Rhyme {

private:
    string a;

public:

    Rhyme ();

};

#endif
```

**Alphabet.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Alphabet.h"

using namespace std;

Rhyme::Rhyme () {

    a = "A for Apple";
}
```

**Main.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Alphabet.h"

using namespace std;

int main () {

    Rhyme rhyme;
    return 0;
}
```

Linux terminal command:

```
g++ *.cpp
./a.out
```

After this I am getting the following error:

Error:

```
    In file included from Alphabets.cpp:2:0:
Alphabet.h:10:2: error: ‘string’ does not name a type
  string a;
  ^
Alphabets.cpp: In constructor ‘Rhyme::Rhyme()’:
Alphabets.cpp:8:2: error: ‘a’ was not declared in this scope
  a = "A for Apple";
  ^
In file included from Main.cpp:2:0:
Alphabet.h:10:2: error: ‘string’ does not name a type
  string a;
```

I am trying to declare a `string member variable` in `header file` as `private`, and then initialize it from another file using `constructor`

Comment: Both are legal. I think you are getting an error because you are missing `#include <string>` in your header file.

Comment: Without knowing what errors (if any) you get all we can do is guess. Please [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Oh and the code snippets you show are really not valid, any of them. `#ifndef` and `#define` *what*?

Comment: It's always a good idea to post the concrete error message you are seeing. I guess that @Ivan is right about the missing include.

Comment: Because 'std::string' is not a primitive type. You need the header.

Comment: you should include related header of string which is `#include <string>` and also declare it as `std::string` or add `using namespace std;` statement before class declaration

Comment: @OnurA. Note that [`using namespace std;` is not good practice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice). Especially in header files.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I agree, I just offered alternative solutions to his problem ;)

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude updated my answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In C++, `int` is a builtin keyword and is a valid type anywhere in the code. `string` is a class in the `std` namespace defined in the `<string>` header and may only be used if you include the header first.

You should not use the `using namespace` directive in header files (namespace pollution), so you need to write `std::string`.

Also, use the file name of your header (e.g. SAMPLE_H) for include guard:

```
#ifndef SAMPLE_H
#define SAMPLE_H

#include <string>

class Sample {
    private:
        std::string name;
};

#endif
```

Answer (score 1):

`std::string` is a standard user-defined class that is declared in the header `<string>`. So you need to include the header

```
#include <string>
```

and is placed in the standard name space `std`.

So you need at least write

```
class Sample {
    private:
        std::string name;
};
```